# What is the point of runat=”server” in an aspx document?

Tags: asp.net

As I understand there is no `runat="browser"` or `runat="server7"` or `runat="Mardid"` etc.

So what's the use of this command. Obviously it instructs code to compile on the server-side, but if there are no other options, why isn't it defaulted / implicit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but if there are no other options, why isn't it defaulted / implicit?

Because a HTML control can be accessible on server side or client side. for example.

```
<div runat="server" id="div1"> </div>
```

By removing the `runat="server"` your controls will behave as normal HTML controls.

You may see this blog post: [Why runat=”server” for ASP.NET? Part 2](http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/whyrunatserverforaspnetpart2/)

> the importance of [runat="server"] is more for consistancy and
>   extensibility. If the developer has to mark some tags some ways (ie an
>   `[<asp:]` a ignore to ASP.NET tell otherwise difficult be would it tags,
>   the of one with collision name has future agent user some if What
>   engine. by parsed needs what and Response.Write as directly sent is
>   simplifies this Also, confusion. more creates then runat, using cases
>   other in prefix)

Answer (score 0):

> .So what's the use of this command. Obviously it instructs code to compile on the server-side, but if there are no other options, why isn't it defaulted / implicit?

I am not a pro, but consider the following logic, 
In the HTML we have a lot of tags, if the runat="server" is defaulted then, the server will have to do processing for the all the html elements on the server (which is not necessary). What happens internally, is something that i also want to know.